# How do I access a repeat control from the outside e.g. via CSJS

Tags: xpages

How can/should I access a repeat control from outside? In my case I want to calculate some additional value(s) for the items in the repeat control and update each item with jquery.

Comment: You could give the items a class and use $(".classname").. .to do things to them.

Comment: OK I understand that one should work. Is there a SSJS alternative that you perhaps know?

Comment: I'm bit confused there - jquery is a client side library so it;d have to run in the browser after the page loads. SSJS would be server-side (of course) so no jquery available there.. is that where the problem is ? you need something like jquery but for server-side ? I guess the answer would be just more SSJS

Comment: no I am interested in both options: CSJS with jquery and SSJS.

Answer (score 0):

In SSJS you always access a component with getComponent("id"). If your contents of the repeat are just a view than define the view data source at the XPage level, not the repeat and you can use the id of the datasource to get the view object, ie, view1.

Answer (score 0):

From SSJS you can access the repeat control itself via getComponent(). However, if you want to access components within the repeat, it gets more challenging.

The default behaviour is to create a single "row" of components for the repeat and then, in the Render Response phase, iterate over them to generate the relevant HTML for the appropriate number of rows (`rows` property of the repeat control) from the relevant start point (`first` property of the repeat control, which may have been incremented by a pager), picking the data from the relevant data (`value` property of the repeat).

If the repeat has `repeatControls="true"` set, at page load the runtime creates a set of controls for the appropriate number of rows (`rows` property of the repeat control). However, accessing them may still be a challenge. This will also remove the ability to use a pager.

If you want to manipulate e.g. the appropriate view entries within the repeat, one option might be to load into viewScope the UNID / Note ID via a computed property within each row. E.g.

```
rendered="#{javascript:if (view.isRenderingPhase()) {
  if (idex == 1) viewScope.put("myVar", new java.util.ArrayList());
  viewScope.get("myVar").add(entry.getNoteID());
  return true;
} else {
  return true;
}"
```

This initialises (or re-initialises) the viewScope variable if it's the first row (please double-check first row has `idex` as 1, `idex` being the variable name you define for the `indexVar` property of the repeat control), and adds the NoteID to the list. So element 0 is the NoteID of the first row, element 1 the Note ID of the second row etc.

If you wish to manipulate values, you may be able to take a similar approach by using dynamic binding. There are various questions on StackOverflow about dynamic binding for repeat controls as well as blog posts, probably by either Tim Tripcony or Jesse Gallagher.

Beyond this, CSJS may be the easiest way to manipulate the contents of the repeat. Just be aware that if you do a partial refresh whose refreshId is the repeat, it may replace whatever you've done client-side.